# Convert service from xml to yaml or import xml to yaml

Tags: php, xml, symfony, yaml, sonata-admin

I have service in XML:

```
<service id="sonata.news.admin.comment" class="%sonata.news.admin.comment.class%">
    <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="sonata_blog" label="comments" label_catalogue="%sonata.news.admin.comment.translation_domain%" label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore" />
    <argument />
    <argument>%sonata.news.admin.comment.entity%</argument>
    <argument>%sonata.news.admin.comment.controller%</argument>

    <call method="setTranslationDomain">
        <argument>%sonata.news.admin.comment.translation_domain%</argument>
    </call>

    <call method="setCommentManager">
        <argument id="sonata.news.manager.comment" type="service"/>
    </call>

    <call method="setTemplates">
        <argument type="collection">
            <argument key="inner_list_row">SonataNewsBundle:Admin:inner_row_comment.html.twig</argument>
            <argument key="base_list_field">SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_flat_field.html.twig</argument>
        </argument>
    </call>
</service>
```

How can i convert this service to yaml?
I can:

```
sonata.news.admin.comment:
    class: Sonata\NewsBundle\Admin\CommentAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "sonata_blog", label: "comments" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\Comment
        - Sonata\NewsBundle\Controller\Comment
    calls:           
      - [ setTranslationDomain, [SonataNewsBundle]]
      - [ setCommentManager ]
```

All working good except last line - setCommentManager. I have error:

```
CommentAdmin::setCommentManager() must be an instance of Sonata\NewsBundle\Model\CommentManagerInterface, none given
```

How can i pass this instance?

Perchance how can i import this service in xml file to yaml?

I want to make some changes in this service.

**Edit:**
Next i i would like pass SetTemplates in this service, but how can i make in this example with 2 arguments?

Comment: To pass a service you need the `@` operator. `[ setCommentManager, [ @sonata.news.manager.comment ] ]`

Comment: thanks, working ok. I updated my question - please add answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call the \_\_invoke method of a member variable inside a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603316/how-to-call-the-invoke-method-of-a-member-variable-inside-a-class)